# What are the actions a system can take when a deadlock is detected?

Tags: programming-languages, operating-system, system, deadlock

I'm having a little bit of trouble understanding how to handle deadlocks.  First of all, what are some of the actions one can take?  Additionally, what action is usually taken, and which is "best"?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can't always detect deadlocks in the first place due to the Halting Problem.

But assuming you have reasonable suspicion that is has occurred, then you don't have much choice. You can:

- Interrupt (i.e. send a signal/exception to) all the threads holding the lock. They will have to be able to handle the resulting interrupt, though.
- Kill all the threads/processes involved. This is a drastic action, and it saves the rest of the system at the expense of the risk that some data will probably be lost by the program.

Comment: dead lock != infinite loop [unless I am mistranslating...], thus it is not the halting problem. AFAIK dead locks and data races can be found even statically, but it is NP-Complete.

Comment: @amit: It's certainly easy to detect if two threads are waiting for each other, but how will you know that a *third* thread doesn't plan on waking them up? It obviously depends on the kind of the deadlock, and the assumptions you make.

Comment: If it can be done statically, it can also be done dynamically by analyzing the byte-code. I am certain that data races can be found statically, and it is NP-Complete, I might be mistaken for the deadlocks issue, can you offer a reduction?

Comment: On a second thought I *think* you are correct, deadlocks seems to be harder issue then data-races... But I'd still be glad to see a reduction, got ideas? :\

Comment: @amit: I'm not convinced even data races can be found either statically *or* dynamically... after all, how can you figure out whether a data race will occur, if you don't even know if the program will *reach* that dangerous point in the first place (due to the halting problem)?

Comment: It's a fair point you are giving. I might be confusing with a bounded model or something, I'll have to re-read the data-race issue. Anyway, you got +1 from me for this enlighnting fruitful discussion, and of course - a nice answer.

Comment: @Mehrdad AFAIK, deadlocks can be detected if we consider threads/transaction that acquire exclusive locks, which is the common case. Deadlocks might not be detectable for other settings, but your answer gives the impression that deadlock detection is inpractical, while it is.

Comment: IIRC, deadlocks can be found dynamically with reasonable efficiency -- they're indicated by a cycle in the wait graph.

Comment: @comingstorm: Like I said, that's only a special case of a deadlock. If there's a third thread that might wake both of you up, that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking how to **handle** deadlocks. **This is not the right question**: You should avoid them. Make sure they don't happen because, realistically, your program cannot recover from them.

Comment: I think you will be interested in this paper "Deadlock Immunity". http://dslab.epfl.ch/pubs/dimmunix It's somewhat between prevention and handling.

Answer (score 0):

You can kill some of the deadlocked tasks, and hope the others can then proceed, and will not remain in, or immediately fall back into, deadlock.  This is not particularly reliable.

You can kill all the deadlocked tasks.  That will free up resources that would otherwise never be used without outside intervention.  However, your tasks are now dead -- and if you start them all up again, there's no reason why they can't deadlock again.

As @usr says, the right thing to do is to avoid deadlocks in the first place.  Any potential deadlock indicates a serious flaw in your system, and should probably cause you to rethink your design.

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily prevent resources from deadlocked processes.
Back off a process to some check point allowing preemption of a needed resource and restarting the process at the checkpoint later.
Successively kill processes until the system is deadlock free.